# DateTime.ParseExact weekdays as text throws FormatException

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

Why does the last line using DateTime.ParseExact throw a FormatException explaining that the provided string (datetimeAsString) is not valid because the weekday is faulty?

```
var format = "yyyy/M/ddd";
var provider = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // Have tried with several other cultures including Invariant
var datetime = new DateTime(4444, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 777);
var datetimeAsString = datetime.ToString(format, provider);

// Here datetimeAsString == "4444/3/Wed"
var x = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimeAsString, format, provider);
```

Comment: What result do you expect? There are many Wednesdays in April 4444.

Comment: What date would you expect `4444/3/Wed` to be parsed to? It could be multiple answers which is why you get an exception.

Comment: There may be multiple "Wed" in a month. While the format matches we cannot say that this is the representation of a specific DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the weekday (despite what the exception message says). Your problem is that there are many Wednesdays in March 4444, and the parser doesn't know which one to pick.

If you add in the day of the month to make it unambiguous, it parses:

```
var format = "yyyy/M/ddd/dd";
var provider = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // Have tried with several other cultures including Invariant
var datetime = new DateTime(4444, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 777);
var datetimeAsString = datetime.ToString(format, provider);

// Here datetimeAsString == "4444/3/Wed/02"
var x = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimeAsString, format, provider);
```

[Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YAgtAU)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to set format to

```
var format = "yyyy/M/dd";
```

Then there is no exception.
Here "dd" stands for day number, and "ddd" - for day of the week.

Comment: It looks like, the original question was why it throws the exception, not how to fix it.